# adding plugin check_hping to nagios

Tags: ping, nagios3

I need to checking IP:PORT by ping, so I find out check_hping plugin to nagios. I'm trying to add it to the nagios core 4.

```
http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-Protocols/ICMP/chech_hping/details
```

In the nagios service web interface I got the error :

```
CRITICAL: Error pinging
```

1, it seems that I have correctly added plugin to the plugin folder (permissions, ownership..)

```
root@onedata-desktop:~# ls -l  /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_hping 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nagios nagios 1994 Jul 26 17:36 /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_hping
```

2, All arguments in command are correct:

```
define command{
        command_name    check-ping-on-port
        command_line    $USER1$/check_hping $HOSTADDRESS$ $ARG1$ $ARG2$ $ARG3$
        }
define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name               cam_chodba
        service_description     Kamery
        check_command           check-ping-on-port!100!300!10201
        normal_check_interval   1
        retry_check_interval    1
        }
```

3, nagios user's permissions:

```
root@onedata-desktop:~# cat /etc/group | grep nagios
nagios:x:1001:nagios,www-data
```

4, The command is executable from command line:

```
onedata@onedata-desktop:~$ /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_hping 188.123.99.171 200 300 1201
[sudo] password for onedata: 
OK: Average response time 20 ms; packet loss 0%
```

Maybe you can help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'm sorry my bad english.

The problem is that check_hping requires sudo for its use.

To remedy this, I used the following steps:

-You need to remove sudo from a line in the script(look for PRE variable setting).

-Change the command to the following:

```
define command{
        command_name    check-ping-on-port
        command_line    sudo $USER1$/check_hping $HOSTADDRESS$ $ARG1$ $ARG2$ $ARG3$
        }
```

-Add nagios on sudoers file to use this script without password.

Hope this solution works for you too.

Best regards.